# Add custom legend to seaborn boxplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I use seaborn to generate N boxplots of M methods, and then I color boxplots of each method with a same color. I now want to add just a legend that shows the name of the M methods in the different colors (e.g red_line Method A, blue_line Method B and so on). Any quick way to do this?

```
bplot = sns.boxplot(data=[d for d in data])   
colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]    
color_counter = 0
for i in range(len(data)-len(c)): 
    mybox = bplot.artists[i]
    mybox.set_facecolor(colors[color_counter])
    color_counter = color_counter + 1
    if color_counter == len(methods): 
        color_counter=0   
# COMMENTING NEXT CODE BLOCK AS IT OUTPUTS TEXT ASSOCIATED TO GRAY LINES (I want them to be colored instead) 
# leg = plt.legend(labels=[method for method in methods])
# for legobj in leg.legendHandles:
#     legobj.set_linewidth(12.0)
# params = {'legend.fontsize': 80}
# plt.rcParams.update(params)
plt.legend()  
plt.title('Title')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using something like a dataframe for your measurements, then using the values for a column to add the color? For example one column could be all your measurements, and another the name of the method next to each measurement. As per the examples here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html

Comment: Hi @Bar for various reasons my data is not a dataframe. I am able to do everything myself, but just need to plot a legend with colors (that I know). Are you aware of any quick workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib allows you to create custom legends, with pretty much whatever you want in there.

See https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html

For your case you'd create something like

```py
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color='red', lw=4, label='Method 1'),
Line2D([0], [0], color='green', lw=4, label='Method 2'),
Line2D([0], [0], color='blue', lw=4, label='Method 3')]

# Create the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, loc='center')

plt.show()
```